# Android Fragment findViewById returns Null after inflating View

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments

I'm trying to get an activity to host a fragment, but after inflating the view of the fragment, when I try to access any widgets via findViewById(), it returns null. So in this case mBillTitle is always null, I am not sure what I am missing?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@+id/bill_title"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:gravity="left"/>

    ....

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/bill_detail_title"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    ....
</LinearLayout>

...

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the fragment code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);
    mBill = new Bill();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bill_details, parent, false);
    mBillTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bill_title);
    mBillTitle.setText(mBill.getmShortTitle());
    ...
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `android:text` to `android:id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:text="@+id/bill_title"
```

suppose to be

```
    android:id="@+id/bill_title"
```